# Violation of Amperes circuital law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

How does the magnetic field expressed in perfectly straight lines from a magnetic north pole to a south pole violate amperes law?(As my textbook says that it will )

On the contrary, what would make it affirm Amperes law if the lines were curved?

P.S I know that magnetic field lines aren't perfectly straight from a North Pole. It's just that I don't get the connection between amperes law and curvature of magnetic field lines.
Pls help

Here's the solved question in my book that gave me the trouble:
[image: Question]
[image: Given diagrams]
[image: Answer for solenoid]
[image: Answer for horseshoe magnet]

Comment: Honestly I'm not quite sure what your text might be getting at. Maybe something has been lost in relaying what it says to us, or in translating to English. But  maybe think about what is the curl of a vector field where the field is all aligned?

Comment: Please check the edited question and let me know if it was of any good.

Comment: Okay, I stand by my clue. "the connection between amperes law and curvature of magnetic field lines" is that one side of Ampere's law is the **curl** of the magnetic field. What is the curl of a field with all (vector) values being paralllel?

Comment: The amperian loop (the one side) can be taken in any shape arbitrarily. So, we can take a rectangular loop n still validate the law. Just what I think. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Look at the differential version rather than the integral version of the equation.

Comment: I don't seem to get it.

Comment: @ThePhoton unclear what your point was. The curl of a constant field is zero, which is absolutely fine, inside or outside the solenoid. It is the fact that the field *becomes* zero abruptly that is the problem, because it requires a current.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you continue the straight-line magnetic field *beyond* the end of the solenoid. Now construct a closed rectangular loop that sits beyond the end of the solenoid, with one side parallel and within the region with a magnetic field, and the opposite side in the region *without* any magnetic field, and the other two sides perpendicular to the magnetic field.

Ampere's law for static fields would be
$$\oint \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l} = \mu_0 I_{\rm encircled}$$
The left hand side of Ampere's law is your B-field multiplied by the length of the rectangle, *but the loop encircles no current*, so the right hand side is zero.

The same argument applies between the poles of a magnet with straight field lines. A rectangle could be constructed that has a non-zero closed line integral of B-field but which encircles no current.

Answer (score 0):

N pole can be considered as a single loop carrying current. Now consider an open surface in the plane of this loop. Boundary of this surface can be considered an American loop. Now current threading the apmerian loop is zero ( b'coz current loop is in the plane of amperian loop )so net no of mag field lines threading the loop must be zero (in accordance with amperes law /B.dl =uI) which is not possible if we consider that lines are straight. 
If the the lines are curved then no of line entering the loop may become equal to the no of line leaving the loop (making a u turn within the loop).I Hope the ans is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

NCERT says , in ampere circuital law  the magnetic field they were mentioning is the component tangential to the 
Amperean loop .so 'if the magnetic field is straight line and also normal to the length of the amperean loop in the plane of the loop , the tangential component which we need by taking normal component of the given field comes to zero
. I think it may be correct
.